# PLPGSQL array indexing start at 1?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I have found that, by default, the first index of an array in PLPGSQL starts at 1, and not 0 like most programming languages.  I was just curious as to why this is, and what other programming language follow this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What languages follow the default array indexing at 1?

ALGOL 68, COBOL, Fortran (if not specified otherwise), FoxPro, Lua, MATLAB, ... anyway, the list is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29).

Comment: very interesting! I had no idea that such powerful programming languages had those indexing methods.

Comment: Not to forget Pascal where you can even define at which index your array starts when you declare the variable